# Are SWIG method/class naming conventions different cross-platform?

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++, mingw, swig

I am trying to create python bindings for a C++ shared library with SWIG, using the CMake approach (swig_add_library, link_libraries).

All the headers are included in only one mymodule.i file.

On Ubuntu everything works fine, all the classes and methods are correctly generated.

On Windows (both with MSVC and MinGW compilers) the classes are not generated.

I tried to add %include < windows.i > to the mymodule.i interface file but it does not change anything. At some point I tried to set the cmake policy CMP0078 (but it does not have any effect on this).

I get the .pyd file on Windows, but it is not correctly generated. Can't figure out what is the difference between the compilers - or what minor thing am I missing.

For example, we have:
    class Device:
            methods: getName()
                    getDescription()
    class Buffer:
            methods: getLength()
                    setLength(int)

After compiling, if we the python help(module/class) functionality in Ubuntu, we get the expected structure:

```
 help(mymodule)     
            NAME        mymodule
            CLASSES     Device Buffer etc. 

 help(Device)
    class Device(object):
        Methods:
            getName(...)
            getDescription(...)

    etc..
```

However, on Windows:

```
  help(mymodule)
    NAME        mymodule
    FUNCTIONS   Device_getName(...)
                Device_getDescription(...)
                Buffer_getLength(...)
            etc

  help(any Device/Buffer object)
    class SwigPyObject(object)
        none of the defined methods are in here
```

Is there any calling/naming convention that SWIG uses on Linux vs. Windows? Why are all the method names prefixed by the class name?

Edit:

This is the cmake configuration:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(UseSWIG)

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME}.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set_property(SOURCE ${PROJECT_NAME}.i PROPERTY SWIG_MODULE_NAME "libm2k")

SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} TYPE SHARED LANGUAGE python SOURCES ${PROJECT_NAME}.i)

target_include_directories(_${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(_${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

This is the library export configuration:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef LIBM2K_EXPORTS
        #define LIBM2K_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define LIBM2K_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define LIBM2K_API __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
#endif
```

Comment: Looking at what's generated on Windows, it feels like it came from `C` code. How is your generation configured?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the cmake configuration for the python bindings. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Is the library export configuration seen by swig as well? The `%include <windows.i>` is necessary for the calling convention on windows as I recall, but Swig must see this `LIBM2K_API` macro as well.

Comment: So SWIG should see LIBM2K_API as __declspec(dllexport) ? 
When writing this (on linux) in order to compile it, I had to undefine LIBM2K_API and define it again in the libm2k.i file (just #define LIBM2K_API). Otherwise it complains in the first header file where this macro is used. ("Syntax error in input").

Comment: I checked back the doc and it seems to mention something like that for windows as well: http://swig.org/Doc4.0/Windows.html#Windows_interface_file

Comment: With respect to export configuration, it is a good idea to include both `%include <windows.i>` and the header defining LIBM2K_API in `libm2k.i` In this way, you don't need to define or undefine LIBM2K_API. Also, you could use CMake to generate the export headers